# My sml compiler doesnot recognize simple operations on arrays (update(arr,int,int), array(int,int) etc). Help!

Tags: arrays, smlnj, initialization, operations

I installed the sml interpreter from here : http://www.smlnj.org/, I used the self extracting .EXE for windows. (I'm running windows7 64 bit)

Although simple operations on basic datatypes are working, it is not recognising operations on arrays/vectors (update, array constructor etc). Do i need to install something else as well to make it work?

Maybe there's a problem in my understanding of the syntax, could someone provide an example code which say declares an array of length 10, initialized to 0 and then adds 1 to each value?

**noob alert**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in SML/NJ:

```
- Vector.map (fn (a) => a+1) (Vector.tabulate (10, fn (a) => 0));
val it = #[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] : int vector
```

The operations on vectors are available here:
http://www.standardml.org/Basis/vector.html#Vector:STR:SPEC
And the `#[...]` notation works for creating vectors, as well.